# C# Project Works Fine on Visual C# Express Program Editor but Stops Working When Published

Tags: c#, express, project, publish

I have a C# Windows Application that I develop using Microsoft Visual C# Express Edition 2005.
It works fine when I try running it on the program editor but the moment I publish the project and run it, the program runs but it says "(Project Name) Stopped Unexpectedly" when I try to open a form containing a Crystal Report Viewer and forces me to close the program. All of the Windows Forms work fine when I'm running it on the program editor. I also tried running the .exe file located on the "bin/debug" and "bin/release" folder but it also stops working when opening a form with Crystal Report Viewer. Can someone help me on this? Please.. I might be missing some stuff before I publish the project. THanks for the help...

Comment: Have you checked your event viewer? What is your error logging saying?

Comment: I already left the office. I'll let you know what is stated in the error logs later.

Comment: I developed the project in a 32-bit environment and before I published it, I transferred it on a computer running on a 64-bit platform (the computer where the project is to be installed). I got a "Class Not Registered" Error when opening forms with Crystal Report Viewer but immediately fixed it after changing the Target Platform from "Any CPU" to "x86" in my Visual C# Express Edition 2005. When I published the project and run it, the compatibility issue still seems to be there. "(Project Name) Stopped Unexpectedly" and forces me to stop the program when opening forms with Crystal Report Viewer

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Now I solved the problem. After googling, i found out that the problem is caused by Data Execution Prevention (DEP) turned on. DEP Keeps blocking Crystal Report Viewer from being ran on the program. So I turned off DEP by running cmd as administrator and typing the command "bcdedit.exe/set {current} nx AlwaysOff" and it did the trick.

Thanks for all your replies.